# Webtoon where the world is full of demons, and the MC takes refuge in a bunker where he meets other kids and a professor

Tags: story-identification, manga, webcomics, demons

OK, this webtoon came out recently; it had like 2-4 chapters when I read it, but it probably has more now.

It starts with this kid being chased by a monster and then closing a steel door. As the monster is trying to break the door down, the kid gets a system notice saying he has to defend himself, but first he has to gather energy by being lazy, and I believe the system says the best way is for him to lay down still on the ground.

After this, he defeats the monster, and it turns out that while he was running from the monster, he was getting younger, so he didn't notice he was a kid again till after the monster died. Afterwards, he wakes up to see a girl eating biscuits, and a professor tells him that he (the professor) is the only adult in a bunker full of kids, and that the outside world is full of demons.

I believe 'doom' was in the title, or something synonymous with doom. I think I found it while I was looking on Edelgarde Scans, but I can't remember.

Comment: When you say _"After this, he defeats the monster, and turns out realizes he is a kid again"_, do you mean that the _monster_ turned out to be a kid, or that the _MC_ realised he was a kid? If you mean that the _MC_ realised  he was a kid again himself, does that mean he was an adult at some point? If so, when? And why did the professor tell him he was an adult, if he's actually a kid?

Comment: no turns out while he was running from the monster he as turning younger so he didnt notice he was a kid again till after the monster died and as for the proffeser he said that he the proffeser was the only adult not the mc

Comment: sorry for confusion i wrote this at midnight so i was kind of tired

Comment: do you know it i think i fond it while i  was looking on edelgardescans but i cant remember

Comment: How did he defeat the Monster? Specifically, what superpowers were involved? Do all the Kids have superpowers?

Comment: while he was running from the monster he came into a room and baracaded the door afterwards a system window poped up and toled him he needed to gather energy and the best way to do it was by being lazy and the best way to be lazy is the life still on th floor so he did that then after gathering energy he blastedthe monster with said energy and at the time it was only 2 chapters so i dont know if there are any kids with powers that 2nd chapter eneded with the world was over run with demons

Comment: @Dragon Tamer How certain are you that this was a new release, as opposed to something old that only had a few chapters translated? Do you remember about what month (and year) you would've read this?

Comment: I know it was a new one cause the website I read it on said it was new both chaps had the new sign and it came out the same time the webtoon unbreakable the one where the guy seems to be the only person not to get his memories of the tower it came out after the 5th chapter released and like I said the website I read it on said it was new but if you think it wasnt then try looking at older ones

Comment: ask away im doing my best to try and give as much info as possible this is a real story and i want to find it so i can keep reing it

Comment: but to answer month it would be lat july to early august

Comment: ok maybe this will help on the system screen there were tabs that had each of the 7 sins greed wrath sloth etc and earlier in the 2nd chapter the protagonist planned to get to the lowest lvl of the bunker cause that is supposedly were the person who gave him his system is or so the voice says

Comment: seriously can i have some help with this its a real good read and i want to see if it has been updated

Comment: @DragonTamer No one can answer if they don't know. I've tried searching and haven't found anything.

Comment: thx for help at least it is a good read even though it was short time

Comment: all i can ask is to spread the word and remember this if you find it

Comment: found it its on dragon tea you should read it its good it went from 3 chaps to 6 right now

Answer (score 6):

This is ***[Tomorrow's Disaster](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/tomorrows-disaster)***.

From Anime-Planet:

> Due to a monster invasion, humans have become in danger. In this era a prodigy was born. The prodigy said don’t! Don’t pull me up! I’m telling you the truth, I study better lying down! This is called effective learning! I’m not sleeping! Laziness is human nature. If everyone can effectively make use of their laziness, they can become the top in humanity and grow smarter.